# C# WebService and DLL not loaded. NIGHTMARE

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, dll

I've a problem running a C# Web Service. I'm Calling a VB6 DLL from a method (AceptaTools.dll) and this DLL call ca4xml.dll.

When i Invoke the service, i get a message ca4xml.dll not loaded.

Both DLL are in BIN folder... Why can't load??Please help.

```
    //Eliminar la marca de comentario de la línea siguiente si utiliza los componentes 


[WebMethod]

public string Send(string Ip, string Puerto, string NroDocumento, string TipoDocumento, string Comando, string Impresora, string Linea)
{
    try
    {
        int _Result = 0;
        string _Null = "";
        string _objURL;

        //Config Capsula
        string serverConfig = "cfg|" + Ip.ToString() + "|" + Puerto.ToString() + "|10";

        //Impresora FACTURA,1 por Defecto.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Impresora)) { Impresora = "FACTURA,1"; }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NroDocumento)) { NroDocumento = "0"; }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Comando)) { Comando = "generar"; }

        //Nuevo CAXML Cliente
        AceptaTools.CA4XML_Client _CA4XML = new CA4XML_Client();

        _Result = _CA4XML.Send(ref serverConfig, ref NroDocumento, ref Comando, ref Impresora, ref Linea, out _Null);


        if (_Result != 0)
        {
            _objURL = _CA4XML.GetLastResponse(); //Get URL
            return _objURL.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Error";
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: did u try registering them with regsvr32 ?

Comment: Try changing your build platform target to x86.  It may help.

Comment: I've registered, but does not work. I've changed to x86 but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Vb6 only understands COM style loading so that DLL will have to be registered.

Comment: Hey! thanks, I can register 'AceptaTools.dll' without problems. But I can't register ca4xml.dll with regsvr32, the problem persist. I will try to change to X86...